# confusion over System.Web.HttpContext.Current

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

So in a server code of a silverlight app I see multiple references to `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. The question is: if `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is a static property then how is it that different simultaneous requests are processed using different `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` objects?

I guess I'm missing something simple here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each request is serviced by a thread. Put another way, a thread can service only one request at a time.

Now `HttpContext.Current` is backed by [`CallContext.HostContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.callcontext.hostcontext%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which is *effectively* a thread-static property (the property getter / setter works on a per-*thread* basis).

> Gets or sets the host context associated with the current thread.

And that's how `HttpContext.Current` manages to always return the correct context for each request, even when multiple requests are being serviced in parallel - the current thread is associated with a HttpContext, which in turn is associated with a specific request.

Answer (score 0):

It is static but on the current Request.

"Gets or sets the HttpContext object for the current HTTP request."

see: [msdn- HttpContext.Current Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx)